# encoding the URL after the post request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, post, url-encoding

When the visitor has uploaded a file from the URL which was :

```
me.appspot.com/contact.jsp
```

changes to :

```
http://me.appspot.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6bOSMzJWAvFtAg59tmmHbOso2f9vU2Uf9e4oqa3ZxDYiZEXh2P04ZesTAiT2B6seI8JzfdHC7ufiO6E-C4bfIm9qgsjBjc6JJ6X2yhIQEz-WkUrMKE/ALBNUaYAAAAAUBaPuEgAbsrLSPhaMXi5FaOkGPeLI3TI/
```

after the redirect to the same page , from which the user uploaded the file.

```
<form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/contact.jsp") %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
```

Is there any way I change the URL to simple `me.appspot.com/contact.jsp` ? I mean I want to encode the URL to the just mentioned URL. Is there any way I can do this ?

Comment: have you tried URL decoding ??

Comment: @Harmeet Singh what ? why would I do that !

Answer (score 0):

The blobstore upload works by redirecting the upload data to a spacial handler in the AppEngien that is not bound to the limitations of the frontend handlers (like 32MB request limit or 60 seconds timeout). After finishing preforming the upload it redirected to your handler.

You can preform upload to the blobstore using your handler but you will be limited to relativity small uploads.

Comment: but I asked about URL encoding. How after the upload can I change that long URL generated. That generated URL is there even after I have uploaded the file

Comment: I read and sorry I don't understand what you are trying todo. **why** do you need to encode the url?

Comment: I don't like those big URL's and few other reasons

Comment: Also the url that AppEngine gave you might not decode to **your** url,  they might store the mapping internally.

Comment: And read my explanation again, the url is not long because it is encoded some how, it is an internal url used by AppEngine, removing/changing it and the upload would not work.